# xcode 6 test target Mach-O linker error

Tags: ios, xcode, linker

I just finished installing CocoaPods. My app target builds and runs.

I added a `link_with` line in my Podfile to allow cocoapods to also add the frameworks to my Tests target. Now I get some linker errors when trying to run tests. I was able to resolve a missing XCTest error by specifying the XCTest framework in `other linker flags` as in the picture.

[image]

I'm still left with this, which is a reference to a class in my project. There are a couple other references to other classes in my tests that don't seem to cause an error, I can see nothing different `ServerController`.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ServerController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TestServerController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here's my `header search paths`:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To me, this looks like you're trying to compile and run tests on the simulator without actually building for the simulator's processor architecture.

Your test project might have `i386` listed as a valid architecture, but does your main project have it listed there as well?

Check **Valid Architectures** in your build settings for your product's target and make sure `i386` is listed as a valid architecture, then clean and build for testing again.

Comment: I tried adding `i386` to both the tests target and the product target, it didn't seem to change the error, but after I took them out again, the error changed to `x86_64`

Comment: Did you also test with that architecture?

Comment: I did, it's strange because it was all working fine before installing cocoapods. I can see no references to any of those architectures in the pods products either.